# How to symbolize stack traces of a stripped shared library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, linker, shared-libraries

I have a crash report for my app from Google Play services which looks like this:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000001b46a0  library.so
  #01  pc 0000000000604464  library.so
  #02  pc 0000000000c8ed1c  library.so
```

I also have a `.map` file for `library.so` which helps me to locate function names and transform stacktrace into more readable format:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000001b46a0  library.so  foo()
  #01  pc 0000000000604464  library.so  bar()
  #02  pc 0000000000c8ed1c  library.so  zoo()
```

But manually resolving function names is error-prone and it doesn't give me the line numbers is source code which caused the crash.

I've considered an idea to store an unstripped version of `library.so` when publishing new version so that I could use [ndk-stack](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack) tool, but AFAIK function addresses for stripped and unstripped binaries are differ.

So my question is it possible to continue publishing stripped binary and have means to automatically symbolize stack traces with line numbers?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ndk-stack` is exactly built for this purpose, don't worry. You feed the unstripped **library.so** to it, and get the best stack trace you can achieve!

Make sure that you don't mix debug/releas versions, and keep the unstripped version for every binary that goes into production (or make sure that you can reliably rebuild such unstripped version for the corresponding git tag).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to build an unstripped version from commit of a published version, but it symbolizes stacktrace incorrectly. Am I correctly understood that I won't be able to symbolize stacktrace for already published version?

Comment: You must be able to reproduce the commit precisely, including all dependencies. Another catch is to use the same toolchain. If you recently upgraded your NDK, this may cause problems.

Comment: Ok, seems like something differs between build machine and mine, thanks for your help